# Simulate roaming on real device

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

How can I simulate roaming on a real android device, when developing on an app that requires physical devices for testing but need to know the behaviour during roaming. I have Samsung Galaxy S plus and Samsung Galaxy S2 Plus

Answer (score 0):

I brought a roaming card from Lycamobile and it allowed me to enable the phone in the roaming mode.